# Is the Normal force dependent on the density of the object the body is resting on?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces

If a body is resting on the ground, the Normal force equals its weight. If I keep putting another body on top of it, eventually the body will start moving into the ground until the new Normal equals the total weight of the body. I can add more weight on top and the body will move further into the ground. So it appears that the denser the object gets, the more the Normal force.

So my question is 3 folds:

1. Is it accurate to say that the normal force depends on the density of the object that the reference object is sitting on?
2. It appears that when the body starts moving into the ground, the equation at any given time t will be Mg - N(t) = Ma where M is the total mass which essentially says that the force that the ground feels on it at time t is N which will keep changing with time and become Mg at some point where acceleration becomes 0?
3. If I draw a free-body diagram of an object moving horizontally forward(just to distinguish from backward) because of force applied on it, I will have two forces - The external force applied on it and the force of friction resisting its motion and the equation will be
   F - $\mu$mg = ma or
   F = m($\mu$g + a)
   When I draw the free body diagram of the person pushing the object, I will have three forces - the reaction from the body that is being pushed, the force of friction in the forward direction and the force applied by the person in the opposite direction to his/her movement (a kick backwards). The equation for the person will be
   $\mu$Mg -R -F$_{b}$ = Ma or
   R = M($\mu$g -a) - F$_{b}$
   It would seem that perhaps the reaction to Force F will not be the same as F. Shouldn't action and reaction be the same?

Comment: By adding "more weight on top", you are also increasing the volume, so density probably isn't the right way to think about it.

Comment: I found a great answer to 3 in the following article: http://dallaswinwin.com/Newtons_Laws/Newton%20Third%20Law.htm. The reaction is the same.

Comment: Regarding 1, N(t) is higher initially if you are pushing the mass on ground vs. pushing it on a bed of cotton/foam/sponge ... because the body comes to rest quicker on a dense object. That is why I talk about density.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you take all your masses and and squeeze them into a tiny volume, although the density increases, the normal force is the same.

Loosely speaking consider the following:

- Density + Volume = Mass, $m = \rho V$
- Mass + Gravity = Weight, $W= m g$
- Weight + No Motion = Equal and Opposite Normal Force, $N=W$
- Normal Force + Area of Contact = Contact Pressure, $N=\iint P(\vec{r})\,{\rm d}A$
- Contact Pressure + Elasticity = Contact Deflection, $\delta = \frac{1-\nu^2}{E} \iint \frac{P(\vec{r})}{|\vec{r}|}\,{\rm d}A$

Answer (score 0):

1:No it is wrong to say so.in fact N depends on volume and density and thus ultimately on mass.when you add objects on top of one another volume changes with density.

2:yes,truly so.But you talk as if the ground is elastic and takes a considerable amount of time.But since the ground is rigid the time will be negligibly small accelaration will change to 0 instantaneously.

3:The "kick" you say is actually the reaction force.
so just vanish the term Fb and you will see the result.

Comment: 1. What you say is not accurate because I could take the same mass of cotton and wood. The Normal for cotton will take some time to become the same as that of wood (until the cotton gets to the same density as wood.

Comment: 2. I am just presenting a case of a body depressing another body. For my discussions in this case, change of acceleration to 0 in a smaller interval or larger interval is not that important. The point is that N will eventually equal the force applied on the body but not initially. This seems to happen faster for dense objects.

Comment: 3. If I attempt to push a body, I will find myself kicking backwards to move forwards. This is not the reaction on me. This is an active action on my part on an external object - the ground.

Comment: @pran 2.Correct.Now i think question 2 is clear.

Comment: @pran pls elaborate what you wanna say in Qs.1

Comment: @pran Oh you talk of that kick,sorry i thought another thing.Well leave it. Now listen,the kick you give is a force  applied BY YOU AND NOT ON YOU.the reaction of this kick is the friction and they balance each other.Its like this when you push a block,you apply a force.If you draw your F.B.D you will not apply that force on you ,will you?So "kick" being a force given by you, will not appear in your F.B.D. It will be a force on the ground.ALRIGHT?

Comment: Q. 1 What I am saying is that if the surface is dense such as stone, marble, solid wood, the object comes to rest quickly (assuming the falling object is sufficiently heavy). In other words, the dense surface experiences a lot of force close to the time of contact because of which it offers a high normal reaction. A less dense surface, on the other hand, seems to experience much less force close to the time of contact because of which the falling body continues to fall for some time.

Comment: 3. Sorry, I get a lot of sense of ego in that response. I don't think you got the drift of my question. Please understand the question before answering and please stop those screaming bolds when you don't understand the question.

Comment: 3.@pran look there is no sense of ego on my side and i am very sorry if i somehow said anything you did not like.It would be good to clear away all misunderstandings and please tell me what wrong i said .

Answer (score 0):

You start off by saying that normal would take some time before becoming equal to weight of placed body, this is wrong because you are assuming that the bodies will sink in the ground due to their weight, but that is the practical case, in that case the tensile strength of ground gives in and it shows strain till it develops enough stress to counter balance the total weight, the question you are asking is idealisitic and in this case the bodies will not sink in the ground and will remain above the surface of ground at all times.

1st : it is not accurate to say so, since normal force actually depends on massof the body,and mass is a function of both density and volume of the bodh, remeber $ m = \rho V $ so as the volume need not be constant it is inaccurate to say that it depends on density

2nd :  since in accordance with the realm of question, the bodies will not sink into the ground, it can be said as soon as they touch the ground the normal equals their toa weight without any time delay.

3rd : I see that you have used $F_b$ applied by the person on ground in the equations for the block, this is not valid untill you are using for the entire system at once, which wouls also include the reaction from ground to $ F_b$ applied by the person. Individually if you see the reaction from ground would equate $F_b$ the force $F$ applied by person on block and block's reaction $R$, then the rest can be equated as $F - μmg = ma$